# install4j fails to access JRE on remote service

Tags: java, install4j

Executing the installation program for a 64-bit Windows client, I'm confronted with a failure when a required JRE is missing and I choose to let it download the JRE from a remote service (which the client, when installed, will communicate with).

My install4j version is 7.0.12 (build 7368).

The install program is configured to bundle with the JRE labelled "Windows (amd64) 12.0.1".
I selected "Dynamic bundle" and an HTTP download from "${compiler:sys.publisherUrl}/jres/windows-amd64-12.0.1.tar.gz".

At the end of the build process, install4j tells me to

> make sure that the file
> C:\Users\ME.install4j7\jres\windows-amd64-12.0.1.tar.gz can be
> downloaded from
> https://www.NN.de/jres/windows-amd64-12.0.1.tar.gz

I followed this instruction and to confirm that I did it correctly, I entered https://www.NN.de/jres/windows-amd64-12.0.1.tar.gz in a browser and found that I *could download the archive successfully.*

When I run the installer, it doesn't find a suitable JRE, offers to download the JRE and tries to get it, but its attempts aren't successful: after a while it times out and then shows an error dialog, informing me about a problem and asking me to check my internet connection and try again. It also points me to a log file, which says

> [0:368] Searching for a JVM 
> (...) 
> [0:393] Search sequence finished
> [0:394] ERROR: No JVM found
> [0:395] Download location: https://www.NN.de/jres/windows-amd64-12.0.1.tar.gz 
> [7:325] Downloading JRE 
> [7:536] ERROR: HttpQueryInfo (try 1) failed with error code 12150
> (...) 
> [15:805] ERROR: HttpQueryInfo (try 20) failed with error code 12150 
> [16:255] ERROR: Giving up

My questions are obvious: 
What can cause this error? What does "error code 12150" mean? Can a firewall be blocking the request? 
What can I do?

Comment: Why not make it easier on yourself and use a native installer produced by the jdk? It will ship the correct jre: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9

Comment: @g00se Thanks for the hint, skimmed it just now, this sounds promising.